# two one to many relations - each Event has many spots and each spot has many bookings

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I have three tables : Events, Spots and Bookings.
Events has many spots(datetime)and
Spots has many bookings.

I have 'spaces' column in spots table and 'spot_id' in bookings table. And In spots table I need to Sum all the spaces GROUP BY event_id and in bookings table I need to count all the bookings GROUP BY event_id. both the tables have event_id.

I need to query something like:

```
select S.event_id, sum(S.spaces), count(B.spot_id)
from spots S, bookings B
where S.event_id = B.event_id;
```

I need output like:

```
Event_id       sum(Spaces)      count(Bookings)
  1              300                 60
  2              450                120
```

But because its one to many relation, I get sum of spaces wrong. if I hve 60 bookings = 60 rows therefore 60 * actual-sum_of_spaces. That is because I have multiple spots for single Event.

How do I get sum of spaces from table spots where event_id and sametime Get count of all booking given event_id. No. of rows in spots table dont match no.of rows in bookings.

[bookings table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkAqW.png)

[spotstable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4twC6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$events = DB::table('bookings')
             ->join(DB::raw('(select S.event_id, sum(S.spaces) as sum_spaces from spots S group by S.event_id) d'), function($join)
             {
                $join->on('bookings.event_id', '=', 'd.event_id');
             })
             ->select('bookings.event_id', 'd.sum_spaces',
                      DB::raw('COUNT(bookings.event_id)'))
             ->groupBy('bookings.event_id')
             ->get();
```

Comment: I tried the above query and it doesn't get right sum for spaces. I have 62 spaces for event 1 and 6 bookings. But I get 438 spaces and 24 bookings

Comment: Show us data for your tables so that we don't have to guess.

Comment: I have added the screenshots of both the tables. please have a look at it.

Comment: Try running my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate `sum(spaces)` first and join the (derived) result with `bookings` to calculate `count(bookings)`:

```
select event_id, sum_spaces, count(b.event_id) count_bookings
from (
    select S.event_id, sum(S.spaces) as sum_spaces
    from spots S
    group by S.event_id
) d
join bookings b on b.event_id = d.event_id
group by b.event_id
```

Comment: I think he wants a Laravel PHP query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - When look at examples with `sum`, `count` and derived tables i see a lot of `raw` used. So why not just put the complete query ito a single DB::raw?